# Connect IBAction to custom class

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I wrote a custom class called `PressableView`. It recognizes taps and then calls a protocol function on its delegate object. Since it is a subclass of `UIView`, it does not allow the connection of `IBAction`s by default.
I was wondering whether it is possible to connect a function inside the view controller, the pressable view is in, to the object, so it calls that method on tap – just like you would with a `UIButton`.

I already tried things like:

```
class PressableView: UIView {
    // ...
    @IBOutlet var action: (() -> Void)?
    // ...
}
```

...but, Xcode doesn't allow that type to be an `IBOutlet`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `PressableView` parent class as `UIControl` class then you can connect for actions and handle it.

*`UIControl` is subclass of `UIView` class only. so you will have all the properties of `UIView` as well.*

```
class PressableView: UIControl {
     @IBAction func uicontrolEventAction(_ sender: Any) {
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks promising. Can I also define when to call a function myself? Say, I'd like it to only fire when tapped twice?

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks so much!

Comment: anytime my pleasure @LinusGeffarth    !!Happy Coding!! :)